# Was strstream ever part of the standard?

Tags: c++, standards

Recently I've skimmed through n3376 and came across an interesting section in Annex D: [depr.ios.members]. It mentions the "old" IO-classes `strstreambuf`, `istrstream`, ... as deprecated.

Personally I haven't used any of these for any serious program (think I once had to use them in an assignment, but after that i stayed with `<sstream>`).

From what I know these classes were pre-standard, but were they ever part of any standard? If not, I don't quite understand why there are even mentioned in the standard...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, they always were (since 1998) and are part of the standard, but they are deprecated (and always have been, since 1998).

The natural question that follows is: why were they added as deprecated? I can only speculate here, but there is no alternative where you can manage your own buffer, and you can not access the string of stringstream directly, so this template is without a good alternative. The committee will surely be open for a new proposal to fill this gap (that is, control the buffer), but undeprecating strstream is likely a no-no.

Comment: See [Evolving a language in and for the real world: C++ 1991-2006](http://www.stroustrup.com/hopl-almost-final.pdf) where Stroustrup mentions the IO streams suffered from the [second system effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second-system_effect).

Comment: Ok, that clears that up. Kinda strange to add something as deprecated to begin with...

Comment: Anyone looking for an alternative to strstream: see the very bottom of http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/iostreams/doc/index.html.