# How to make istringstream more efficient?

Tags: c++, performance, standards, c++17

```
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

const char* GetHugeString();

int main()
{
    const char* p = GetHugeString();

    //
    // Below will copy the huge string into a std::string object!
    // 
    istringstream sstrm{p}; 

    return {};
}
```

`istringstream` doesn't need a copy of the huge string; a null-terminated string pointer is enough. But `istringstream`'s `ctor` only take `std::string`, rather than `std::string_view`(c++1z only), as its argument.

Is there a work-around to make `std::istringstream` more efficient in such a case?

Comment: I'm not sure is this is the reason, but I suspect this isn't supported because the internal storage is backed by `stringbuf`, which doesn't accept `string_view` (for good reason).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply assign the buffer used internally in the `istringstream`:

```
istringstream stream;
stream.rdbuf()->pubsetbuf(p, strlen(p));
```

This does not copy the string.  Do note that [`pubsetbuf()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/streambuf/streambuf/pubsetbuf/) wants `char*` not `const char*`, but it doesn't actually modify the string, so you might `const_cast` your C string pointer before passing it.

Comment: What you're suggesting [has implementation-defined behavior](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13059195/636019).