# Any way to get an std::string_view from an std::ostringstream without copying?

Tags: c++, iostream, c++17

I know you can't extract an `std::string` from an `std::ostringstream` without copying ([Creating an input stream from constant memory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13059091)).

But is it possible to get an `std::string_view`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

String-streams are not required to store their data in a single contiguous array. `string_view` is of course a view into a contiguous string.

So no, what you want is not possible. Best wait till C++20, when we get move support into/outof string-streams.