# How to convert QByteArray to std::istream or std::ifstream?

Tags: c++, qt, std, istream, qbytearray

I want to create `istream` from `QByteArray` at runtime, without saving a physical file in memory of `QByteArray`.

I found that there are many ways to do the opposite conversion, i.e. `istream` to `QByteArray`, but not this one.

How to accomplish that?

Comment: It's fairly "easy", if you use Boost with a filtering I/O stream, and "easy", by like 200+ lines of code with fairly difficult to read documentation.

Another option would be to write your own filtering istream from scratch, which is also a total PITA (I've done it, myself, many times, and IO streams have to be the worst part of the C++ standard). Much easier would be to write an overload from QByteArray to istream and to ostream by overloading `operator<<` and `operator>>`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To read via `std::istringstream` from `QByteArray` seems quite easy:

`testQByteArray-istream.cc`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <QtCore>

int main()
{
  qDebug() << "Qt Version:" << QT_VERSION_STR;
  // make a QByteArray
  QByteArray data("Hello Qt World.");
  // convert to std::string
  std::istringstream in(data.toStdString());
  // read from istringstream
  for (;;) {
    std::string buffer;
    if (!std::getline(in, buffer)) break;
    std::cout << "Got: '" << buffer << "'\n";
  }
  // done
  return 0;
}
```

`testQByteArray-istream.pro`:

```
SOURCES = testQByteArray-istream.cc

QT = core
```

Compiled and tested on [cygwin64](http://www.cygwin.org):

```
$ qmake-qt5 testQByteArray-istream.pro

$ make

$ ./testQByteArray-istream 
Qt Version: 5.9.4
Got: 'Hello Qt World.'

$
```

Done. Stop, wait!

> without saving a physical file in memory

I'm not quite sure how to read this. Probably, it means

**without copying data saved in `QByteArray`**

I see only two solutions:

1. Use a `QDataStream` instead of `std::stream`. According to doc. [`QDataStream::QDataStream(const QByteArray &a)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatastream.html#QDataStream-3)

   > Constructs a read-only data stream that operates on byte array a.

   This sounds *very* promising that data is not copied.
2. DIY. Make a class derived from `std::stream` which may read from a `QByteArray` without copying.

Concerning 2. option, I found Dietmar Kühl's answer to [SO: Creating an input stream from constant memory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13059195/7478597). Applying this to the above sample, it would look like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <QtCore>

// borrowed from https://stackoverflow.com/a/13059195/7478597
struct membuf: std::streambuf {
  membuf(char const* base, size_t size) {
    char* p(const_cast<char*>(base));
    this->setg(p, p, p + size);
  }
};
struct imemstream: virtual membuf, std::istream {
  imemstream(char const *base, size_t size):
    membuf(base, size),
    std::istream(static_cast<std::streambuf*>(this)) {
  }
};

int main()
{
  qDebug() << "Qt Version:" << QT_VERSION_STR;
  // make a QByteArray
  QByteArray data("Hello Qt World.");  
  imemstream in(data.data(), (size_t)data.size());
  // read from istringstream
  for (;;) {
    std::string buffer;
    if (!std::getline(in, buffer)) break;
    std::cout << "Got: '" << buffer << "'\n";
  }
  // done
  return 0;
}
```

Compiled and tested again on [cygwin64](http://www.cygwin.org):

```
$ qmake-qt5 testQByteArray-istream.pro

$ make

$ ./testQByteArray-istream 
Qt Version: 5.9.4
Got: 'Hello Qt World.'

$
```

Comment: Thank you...I need time to go through the solution..and let you jnow