# How to get and std::ifstream object from a FILE* one

Tags: c++, c, c++11, gcc, g++

I'm trying to refactor some code/libraries by trying to embed some resource files as binary objects using the objcopy tool. The files are `.txt` and `.xml`.

The original library contains some file read/write code, based on `fopen`, which I replaced by `fmemopen()` in order to load the files from memory instead of getting them from the disk.

My issue is that, the library also contains some `std::ifstream` objects that are used to read some other files from disk, and my question is how can I read those too from the memory?

I.e. I need either to assign a FILE* to an ifstream somehow, or if there is an equivalent of `fmemopen()`that is used for ifstreams.

```cpp
std::ifstream input(pathToFilters);
```

**NB. Please note that I'm trying to get an ifstream FROM a FILE and not the inverse (which has been already answered)**

Thanks!

Comment: I used the following solution finally.
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13059091/creating-an-input-stream-from-constant-memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13059091/creating-an-input-stream-from-constant-memory)

Answer (score 1):

Rather than open a `FILE *`, then try to create a stream from that, it's almost certainly going to be easier to create an `istream` that reads directly from memory.

An `istringstream` reads from a memory buffer, so that part is pretty easy.

So, you can create an `istringstream` object, passing it the data you want to read from, and then pass the `istringstream` to the code that expects to read from a stream. Normally, most code that deals with a stream should accept a reference to an `istream` or an `ostream`, in which case it'll accept a `stringstream` just as well as an `fstream`.

Comment: I searched about `istringstream`, and found out that to construct an object you need to give it a string, does this mean that I have to read all the files mapped to memory to a string then pass it as an argument to construct the `istringstream` ? Not sure if my understanding is correct. This solution would very inefficient I guess. I would like to have something that would read directly from the memory.