# Is it possible set the base level of Emitter indentation in yaml-cpp?

Tags: c++, yaml, yaml-cpp

Is there a one-time way to set the base level of indentation for all values that `Emitter` emits in yaml-cpp?

I tried using `Emitter::SetIndent` and `Emitter::SetLocalIndent` but those only seem to affect items below the root level of the emitter, not root level items themselves

To illustrate, consider the following, ***desired*** YAML output.  Values start off indented by 4 spaces already (my comments to the right are not part of the output)

```
    type: Circle            // Correctly indented by 1 level (4 spaces)
    r: 492.763875219
    x: 1286.75555556
    y: 1195.04
    regions:
      - id: 1750272850      // Correctly indented by 2 levels (8 spaces)
        width: 200
      - id: 524770566
        width: 42
```

I tried to write it out with this code:

```
void Shape::writeToYaml(std::ostream& os)
{
    YAML::Emitter out;      
    out.SetIndent(4);         // THIS DOES NOT HELP
    out << YAML::BeginMap;

    for (auto&& prop : properties())   // 'properties()' returns std::map<string, string>
        out << YAML::Key << prop.first << YAML::Value << prop.second;
    out << YAML::Key << PK_REGIONS << YAML::Value;
    out << YAML::BeginSeq; 
    for (auto&& region : m_regions)
        out << region.properties();  // 'properties()' returns std::map<string, string>

    out << YAML::EndSeq;
    out << YAML::EndMap;

    os << out.c_str();
}
```

Instead I got this output where the root values are not indented at all and the values below those are indented by too much

```
type:   Circle                         // WRONG: NOT INDENTED AT ALL
r:      492.763875219
x:      1286.75555556
y:      1195.04
regions:
        -       id:     2077164443     // WRONG: INDENTED BY TOO MUCH
                width:  200
        -       id:     2031385931
                width:  42
```

(I'm trying to adapt existing yaml-writing code without exposing yaml-cpp types in my API, so I need to be able to create Emitters on the fly and then just set their base indentation.  I'm using the latest, 0.6 version, downloaded yesterday)

Answer (score 1):

afaik yaml-cpp can't do this for you, but the workaround is quite simple:

```cpp
std::stringstream ss(out.c_str());
std::string line;
while (std::getline(line, ss)) {
  os << "    " << line << std::endl;
}
```

To avoid copying the emitter's output string, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13059195/347964).